# Show a specific String on output PHP

Tags: php, string, output

I have this php code :

```
 <?php
       $output = shell_exec('wmic os get osarchitecture');
       echo "$output";
  ?>
```

The output is : OSArchitecture 64 bits.

I just want to show "64 bits"  without "OSArchitecture" .

Any help  would be appreciated .

Comment: http://php.net/substr

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on how predictable your returned string is. You could simply output a substring like:

```
echo substr( $output, -7 ); // Or -8 if the '.' in your question is part of $output
```

or splitting the string on spaces and output that last two pieces would work:

```
$pieces = explode( ' ', $output );
echo $pieces[1] . ' ' . $pieces[2];
```

or a regular expression could be used, but that might be overkill.

Comment: Both options work fine.just a correction echo substr( $output, 14 );instead of -7 .Thanks .

Comment: Sure. The substring version will fail if sometime in the future the returned string is changed to 'OSArch 64 bits' and the explode version will fail if the returned string is changed to 'OSArchitecture 64bits'. So, unless you have control over what 'wmic' returns you need to think about keeping your code from failing in the future from what others might do.

Answer (score 0):

```
   $output = shell_exec('wmic os get osarchitecture');
 echo $test= str_replace("osarchitecture","",strtolower($output));
```